# How to auto-format whitespaces in comments using android studio?

Tags: android-studio, comments, code-formatting

My problem is, when I comment out a line using Ctrl + /,

```
//        comment
```

and then auto-format the code,

```
        //        comment
```

the comment will still contain whitespaces after the "//" that I wouldn't want to keep.

I've already checked the Settings>Editor>Java>Wrapping and Braces options, and also the other tabs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have just solved this problem.

**Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation**

There is a "Comment Code" and deselect the "Line comment at first column"

**Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces**

There is a "Keep when reformatting" and deselect the "Comment at first column"

As follows

[Code Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l23a.png)

[Wrapping and Braces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epMeJ.png)

I think your problem can be solved.

Comment: Not work in the version, Chipmunk|2021.2.1 Patch1

Answer (score 0):

To apply identation to a document press Ctrl + Alt + L (Option + Command + L in Mac)

But the only way, once you have few comments with that "problem", I guess is to replace ('//      ' by '//') (Shortcut to replace: Ctrl + Shift + R)

Hope it hepls.

Comment: I mean '//        (few spaces or tbas here)' by '//'